# uTorrent or Transmission web interface hosted on web server

Tags: proxy, webserver, bittorrent, transmission, utorrent

Is it possible to host my Transmission or uTorrent web interface on my web server? They have a local network web interface, and I don't want to port forward... Can I somehow configure it to it to log into my server and host the interface there?

Comment: You could set up a reverse proxy over an SSH tunnel... if you really wanted to...

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: It was kind of a joke.  But you could do it by using the `-R` argument to `ssh` to reverse-forward a port to your torrent client's web interface, if your hosting company allows `-R`.  Then you'd set up a reverse proxy in Apache over the forwarded port.

Comment: wow.... o.O interesting! i think i might. thank you!

Comment: enjoy the rep from upvoted comments :)

Comment: @tekknolagi, you don't get rep for upvoted comments...sorry. Only questions.

Comment: @cdhowie, you might want to consider posting this suggestion as an answer, since it seems to have been helpful to the OP.

Comment: oh....darn. he should answer it then

Comment: @cdhowie answer it! and more upvotes if you include some detail :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port forwarding would have served as an appropriate answer... It works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, since all of you asked for a kludge, here it is.

You can set it up so you can access the web interface *through* your web hosting account, with the following restrictions:

- The actual interface will still be hosted by your torrent client, but you will be able to reach it via your website.
- Your host must allow remote port forwards (`ssh -R`).  Most VPS hosts will allow this; shared hosting will probably not.
- Your host must allow you to configure Apache with the `ProxyPass` directive, which means that you must have write access to some part of the Apache config (not `.htaccess` files) and your host must load (or allow you to load) `mod_proxy` into Apache.
- Your host *should* allow the installation of an SSH public key so that you can survive an ssh disconnection without needing to enter a password to reconnect.

Here's the basic idea.  Let's call the port that your web interface is served on locally port L.  Pick some random port in the range 49152-65535 and call it S; this is the port that the server will be listening on.

Create an SSH key for this setup, and do not encrypt the private key with a password (hit enter when prompted).  Use `ssh-keygen` for this.  (`ssh-keygen -f $KEY_OUTPUT_PATH` -- pick some file like `$HOME/torrentproxy.key` for the output path.)  Then install the public key on the server: `ssh-copy-id -i $KEY_OUTPUT_PATH.pub user@yourwebhost`.

Create a shell script `torrent-ssh-proxy.sh` with these contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    # Replace S and L with the ports chosen above.
    # Replace $KEY_OUTPUT_PATH with the path to your SSH private key.
    ssh -i $KEY_OUTPUT_PATH -R S:localhost:L user@yourwebhost

    echo 'Disconnected from server.'
    sleep 5
done
```

When you run this, you should get a shell prompt from the server with no password entry required; this is good.  Leave this script running.

(At this point, you might verify that the remote host is in fact listening on port S by running `netstat -tnlp | grep :S` in the server shell.)

Now we need to configure Apache.  You just need to add this to your Apache config (it won't work from `.htaccess` files):

```
ProxyPass /torrentweb http://localhost:S/
```

Again, replace S with the listening port chosen.  Restart Apache.

If this all worked, when you go to `http://yourwebsite.example.com/torrentweb` you should see your torrent client's web interface.

Note that you can run the ssh client on a different box from the web host; just adjust "localhost" in the `ssh` line in the script to match the IP address or hostname of the machine running the torrent web interface.

---

Regarding loading `mod_proxy`, this is how the module is loaded on Debian:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
```

The path to `mod_proxy.so` is likely to be different depending on your distribution's way of arranging package contents in the filesystem.

Comment: Is the Apache config /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ?

Comment: Depending on your distro, yes, it could very well be that.

Comment: Shoot. Is there an alternative file that could have the same effect? On WebFaction (my provider) I cannot edit that file. Could I place the line somewhere else?

Comment: You may be given a per-account Apache config file.  Contact your host for assistance with this.  Also, not that your host must have `mod_proxy` loaded; I would suspect that they do not.

Comment: How would I load mod_proxy? That might be a good thing to add

Comment: I've added a short paragraph on the loading of `mod_proxy`.

Comment: here's my OS: Linux web201.webfaction.com 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Tue Apr 12 18:52:55 EDT 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: That's your kernel build, but not your distro.  I was looking at webfaction -- do you have a hosting plan, or a dedicated server plan?

Comment: Hosting plan...and how do i find my distro?

Comment: If you are on the hosting plan then this *probably* won't work (but it might).  There is no bulletproof way to determine your distro.